# Heisenberg Lie group, image of specific element by any representation is nilpotent

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, heisenberg-group

consider the [Heisenberg group $Heis(\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) and $\mathfrak{h}$ it's Lie algebra. Consider $C\in \mathfrak{h}$ given by

$$C=\begin{bmatrix}
0 && 0 && 1\\
0 && 0 && 0\\
0 && 0 && 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now the goal is to show that for any representation of Lie algebras $\rho : \mathfrak{h} \to \mathfrak{gl}(n,\mathbb{R})$ $\rho(C)$ is a nilpotent matrix. The proof is a bit tricky and the notes I read show that $\rho(C)$ has only $0$ eigenvalues to show that it is nilpotent. But can't we just say $\rho(C)^n=\rho(C^n)=\rho(0)=0$ for some $n$, since $\rho$ is a representation?

Comment: Please, use capitals for the names : Heisenberg, Lie.

Comment: No, representation means that $[\rho(x),\rho(y)]=\rho([x,y]])$ and not $\rho(x)^n=\rho(x^n)$.

Comment: Okay,thank you. I think I was confusing with the notion of representation of a group.